# WxPerl, getting coordinates from wxPoint object

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, point, object-reference

I want solve this problem.

1. get position from specific frame ([wxFrame](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_frame.html)) (function GetPosition() return [WxPoint](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_point.html))
2. Serialize position (x, y) to file
3. set position from file to another window

Everythink is ok, except getting coordinates x and y from [WxPoint](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_point.html) object.
I don't know, how can I acces properties "x", "y" of this object. e.g wxPython allows this by "`somepoint.x`", but WxPerl?  `somepoint->{"x"}` doesn't work, because object is SCALAR reference..

Thank you

Comment: This is just a guess, but does this work: `my $p = $f->GetPosition(); $p->x(); $p->y();`

Comment: Exactly! Thank you

Comment: I've made it an answer now that you've confirmed it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you're looking for:

```
my $point = $frame->GetPosition;

my $x = $point->x;
my $y = $point->y;
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Answer (score 1):

wxPerl and its documentation are a bit of a hackathon. For instance, many packages are defined only in the XS components of the library so it's pretty much impossible to debug. (That's why your `Wx::Point` object is a scalar reference; the scalar value is just a handle on the object's data.)

I have hunted and failed to find a chunk of documentation that I remember from somewhere that explains that WxPerl accesses both attributes and methods in the same way, by a Perl method call

If you look at the [`wxPoint` Class Reference](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_point.html) you will see that there are three constructors: one with no parameters that returns a point at [0,0], one that takes x and y coordinates, and a copy constructor that accepts an existing `wxPoint` object and uses its coordinates. The last of these doesn't work in wxPerl. There are many similar oddities that you must discover for yourself, because the documentation is appalling

Likewise the various "operators" are irrelevant to wxPerl. They could work if the operator were overloaded, but wxPerl is built for speed so this was discarded

As other have described, the two attributes `x` and `y` must be accessed as method calls. (The same applies to attributes of all other classes in wxPerl.)

So you can write

```
my $x = $p->x;
my $y = $p->y;
```

Or, if you want to get funky

```
my ($x, $y) = map { $p->$_ } qw/ x y /;
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution is use (`$p` is instance of `wxPoint`):

```
my $p = $f->GetPosition(); 
$p->x(); $p->y()
```

Comment: `wxPoint` isn't a Perl class